# PHP search (Select with Where more than one value in same field)

Tags: php, mysql

I created a view where I merge all the IDs I need to search.

Every job has a tag

My problem is with tag, I am using LIKE to do the search with more than one value but when I mark several tags and do the search the search returns me a result as if I searched for 1 service at a time.

Ex: I wrote in the research field (1 2 3). If "job1" has the tag "1" and "job2" has the tags "1", "2" and "3" the search should only return "job2" but it returns the 2 jobs.

I already tried using implode () CONCAT () but I don't know how to properly use the no select for this dune

```
 $query = "SElECT * FROM tbBiodata WHERE nama LIKE :q OR hp LIKE :q";
```

or handling of the input i'm doing wrong

```
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="tag" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['q'])){ echo $_GET['q']; } ?>"/>
```

code I'm using this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jobs</title>
    </head>
    <body>

  <h1> Data</h1>     
  <form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="tag" value="<?php if (isset($_GET['q'])){ echo $_GET['q']; } ?>"/> 
  </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
 
 if (isset($_GET['q'])){
    $q = $_GET['q'];     
    $query = "SElECT * FROM tbBiodata WHERE nama LIKE :q OR hp LIKE :q";    
    $q = "%".$q."%"; ////tambahkan tanda persen pada variabel $q         
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); // prepare the query
    $stmt->bindParam(':q', $q); // fill in the value: q from $ q y         
    $stmt->execute(); // query execution
    $jml = $stmt->rowCount(); // check the amount of data from the query
     
 if ($jml>0){ //jika ada data tampilkan
   echo "<table border=\"1\">
     <tr>
       <th>No</th>
       <th>ID</th>
       <th>job</th>
       <th>info</th>
       <th>cas</th>
     </tr>";
  $no=1; 
  
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         extract($row);// change $ row ['field'] to {$ field}
    echo "<tr>
       <td>$no</td>
       <td>{$id}</td>
       <td>{$nama}</td>
       <td>{$alamat}</td>
       <td>{$hp}</td>
     </tr>"; 
   $no++; 
  }
  echo "</table>";   
 } else {
  echo "Search  <b>$_GET[q]</b> not found";
 }
 }
?>
```

Comment: _“where I merge all the IDs”_ – … and that’s where the actual major part of your troubles started. Seriously, this is _not_ a good way to go about this to begin with. Searching with `LIKE :q` makes little sense here - you would at least have to include whatever you used a separator between these ID values, because you don’t want to find 12 or 21, when you are searching for 2.